# XMLSerializer: <ImplementationException xmlns='urn:epcglobal:ale:wsdl:1'> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, rfid

I am trying to deserialize an XML that looks like this:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:ECReports xmlns:ns2="urn:epcglobal:ale:xsd:1" xmlns:ns3="urn:epcglobal:ale:wsdl:1" specName="Cycle_MDEAirport_1" date="2016-04-25T15:06:19.980Z" 
ALEID="RIFIDI-ALE1158647263" totalMilliseconds="9492" terminationCondition="DURATION">
   <reports>
      <report reportName="Cycle_MDEAirport">
         <group>
            <groupList>
               <member>
                  <epc>303400c0e4a3f48000a2f8d5</epc>
               </member>
            </groupList>
         </group>
      </report>
   </reports>
   <ECSpec includeSpecInReports="true">
      <logicalReaders>
         <logicalReader>MDEAirport</logicalReader>
      </logicalReaders>
      <boundarySpec>
         <repeatPeriod unit="MS">10000</repeatPeriod>
         <duration unit="MS">9500</duration>
         <stableSetInterval unit="MS">0</stableSetInterval>
      </boundarySpec>
      <reportSpecs>
         <reportSpec reportName="Cycle_MDEAirport" reportIfEmpty="true" reportOnlyOnChange="false">
            <reportSet set="ADDITIONS" />
            <output includeEPC="true" includeTag="true" includeRawHex="true" includeRawDecimal="true" />
         </reportSpec>
      </reportSpecs>
   </ECSpec>
</ns2:ECReports>
```

**But I get the following error:**

```
<ImplementationException xmlns='urn:epcglobal:ale:wsdl:1'> was not expected
```

**Here is my code:**

```
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "ECReports";
xRoot.Namespace = "urn:epcglobal:ale:xsd:1";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ECReports), xRoot);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(e.Message);
ECReports ECReports;
ECReports = (ECReports)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
```

**The class ECReports that I am using is from a Service Reference (it is not a class developed by me)**

Comment: Add namespace to following line : XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ECReports), "urn:epcglobal:ale:xsd:1");

Comment: Thanks @jdweng , I forgot to include that in my code by error. Now you can see that my updated code include the xRoot in the serializer initialization. The error continues!

Comment: Replace xRoot with xRoot.Namespace.  It is a string value not an Attribute which contains both the name and value.

Comment: @jdweng the xRoot is working well, the problem is with the another namespace (the wsdl one)

Comment: I don't see any xml tags with 'ns3' so I can't tell what the issue is.  What error are you getting?

Comment: ns3 tag is in line 2 - column 52 @jdweng

Comment: It is only the definition of the namespace and since there is no tags that start with the namespace it isn't really being used

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  You are going from a namespace to a non-namespace so you have to specify the namespace as "".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] message = File.ReadAllBytes(FILENAME);
            XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
            xRoot.ElementName = "ECReports";
            xRoot.Namespace = "urn:epcglobal:ale:xsd:1";
            xRoot.IsNullable = true;

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ECReports), xRoot);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(message);
            ECReports ECReports;
            ECReports = (ECReports)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("ECReports")]
    public class ECReports
    {
        [XmlAttribute("specName")]
        public string specName { get; set; } 

        [XmlAttribute("date")]
        public DateTime date { get; set; } 

        [XmlAttribute("ALEID")]
        public string aleid { get; set; } 

        [XmlAttribute("totalMilliseconds")]
        public int totalMilliseconds { get; set; } 

        [XmlAttribute("terminationCondition")]
        public string terminationCondition { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "reports", Namespace = "")]
        public Reports reports { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ECSpec", Namespace = "")]
        public ECSpec  ecSpec { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "reports", Namespace = "")]
    public class Reports
    {
        [XmlElement("report")]
        public Report report { get; set; }
    }    
    [XmlRoot("report")]
    public class Report
    {
        [XmlAttribute("reportName")]
        public string reportName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("group")]
        public Group group { get; set; }

    }    
    [XmlRoot("group")]
    public class Group
    {
        [XmlElement("groupList")]
        public GroupList groupList { get; set; }

    }    
    [XmlRoot("groupList")]
    public class GroupList
    {
        [XmlElement("member")]
        public Member member { get; set; }

    }    
    [XmlRoot("member")]
    public class Member
    {
        [XmlElement("epc")]
        public string epc { get; set; }
    } 

    [XmlRoot("ECSpec", Namespace = "")]
    public class ECSpec
    {
        [XmlAttribute("includeSpecInReports")]
        public Boolean includeSpecInReports { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("logicalReaders")]
        public LogicalReaders logicalReaders { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("boundarySpec")]
        public BoundarySpec boundarySpec { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("reportSpecs")]
        public ReportSpecs reportSpecs { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("logicalReaders")]
    public class LogicalReaders
    {
        [XmlElement("logicalReader")]
        public string logicalReader { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("boundarySpec")]
    public class BoundarySpec
    {
        [XmlElement("repeatPeriod")]
        public Unit repeatPeriod { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("duration")]
        public Unit duration { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("stableSetInterval")]
        public Unit stableSetInterval { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("reportSpecs")]
    public class ReportSpecs
    {
        [XmlElement("reportSpec")]
        public ReportSpec reportSpec { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("")]
    public class Unit
    {
        [XmlAttribute("unit")]
        public string unit { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public int value { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("reportSpec")]
    public class ReportSpec
    {
        [XmlAttribute("reportName")]
        public string reportName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("reportIfEmpty")]
        public Boolean reportIfEmpty { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("reportOnlyOnChange")]
        public Boolean reportOnlyOnChange { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("reportSet")]
        public ReportSet reportSet { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("output")]
        public Output output { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("reportSet")]
    public class ReportSet
    {
        [XmlAttribute("set")]
        public string set { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("output")]
    public class Output
    {
        [XmlAttribute("includeEPC")]
        public Boolean includeEPC { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("includeTag")]
        public Boolean includeTag { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("includeRawHex")]
        public Boolean includeRawHex { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("includeRawDecimal")]
        public Boolean includeRawDecimal { get; set; }
    }

}
```